# How can I use several conditions in a loop to compare different indexes of a string?

Tags: java

so I have this mini-project I'm working for myself on and basically it's a simple method in java for a card game that checks if the string has a flush. Keep in mind I'm a beginner in java(and cardgames/poker...) so I"m new to all of this.

e.g:
the string is ""Kh3h7h8h2s" so the hand is King of hearts, 3 of hearts, 7 of hearts, 8 of hearts, 2 of spades etc. The rank is in the 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th, 9th index of the string. The string needs to have 5 of the same rank to have a flush

```
public class CardProblemss {

String hand = "Kh3h7h8h2h";

public boolean hasFlush(String hand) {
    String suit1 = Character.toString(hand.charAt(1));
    String suit2 = Character.toString(hand.charAt(3));
    String suit3 = Character.toString(hand.charAt(5));
    String suit4 = Character.toString(hand.charAt(7));
    String suit5 = Character.toString(hand.charAt(9));
    int flushcounter = 0;

    while (true) {
    if (suit1.equals(suit2)) {
        flushcounter++;
    }            
    else if (suit2.equals(suit3)) {
        flushcounter++;
    } 
    else if (suit3.equals(suit4)) {
        flushcounter++;
    } 
    else if (suit4.equals(suit5)) {
        flushcounter++;
    } 
    System.out.println(flushcounter);
     if (flushcounter >= 5) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    }  

}
```

Now I can already tell my code is bleh. But my question is, can I formulate a loop that would basically use the charAt(index) method by itself? Since the rank of the hand is at index 1,3,5,7,9, can I write a loop that would increase the index of this method by 2 every time it's ran? Or is there a more efficient way I can do this?
Thanks alot.

Comment: yes, u can... `for(int i=0;i<hand.length();i=i+2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
int flushCounter = 0;

char s = hand.charAt(1); // s for suite
for (int i = 3; i < hand.length(); i = i + 2) {
  if (s == hand.charAt(i)) {
    flushCounter++;
  }
}

if (flushCounter >= 5) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

This way, the only way you'll iterate through the string and then on ever odd value, you'll compare the suite. I'm assuming that you're hand size will always be 3 or more. If you want `i` to start at 1, you can do that too.

```
int flushCounter = 0;
char s; // s for suite

for (int i = 1; i < hand.length(); i = i + 2) {
  if (i == 1) {
    s = hand.charAt(1); 
  } else if (s == hand.charAt(i)) {
    flushCounter++;
  }
}

if (flushCounter >= 5) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

With the latter you have to be careful not to initialize s inside the if statement otherwise it'll go out of scope before you can use it.

Note:

```
if (flushCounter >= 5) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

can be reduced to

```
return flushCounter >= 5;
```

as it will evaluate the expression and then return the result. The former way is much more verbose. Since you are simply returning the value of the expression, I would argue that the latter is simpler.

Comment: or just `return flushCounter == 5` !

Comment: That would be my preference but OP mentioned that s/he is a beginner so I thought being verbose would be better here.

Comment: remember to return false in that case! :P

Comment: Good point! Let me fix that...This is why we have tests... :p

Comment: Thanks! I figured I would end up having to use the for loop. JUst out of curiosity, is null the same as 0? If I were to set char = 0 rather than null(it won't compile with null).

Comment: [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) indicates that the char class is a primitive. The default value is 0 (more accurately '\u0000'). If you don't assign it a value (i.e., you just initialize it) the default value of `char s` will be `0`. If I initialize it to have a value of `null` then `s` has no value associated with it. There is memory allocated for it but nothing put in that space. @flkes ~ anything to add?

Comment: @Nefari0us Actually it simply wont compile. `null`  is a reference can only be used on object types, not primitives.

Comment: ...damn it, you're right. I misread `it won't compile` as `it will compile` and some how I went from char to String. Allow me to redeem myself (because I feel really bad about spreading wrong info):

Char is a primitive and will have a default value of 0. String is a reference type and will store a memory address which will be location of the values in memory. See [this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUQTU.png) image.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's how you can do this with streams!

```
public static boolean hasFlush(final String hand) {
    final char first = hand.charAt(1);
    final long count = hand.chars().filter(c -> c == first).count();
    return count == 5;
}
```