# How do I write an efficient/optimized loop for comparing several conditions at once? Badugi cardgame method

Tags: java

Say, I'm making a simple badugi card game where the Hand is represented by 10 characters in a string. E.g:
2s3h5dQs - 2 of spades, 3 of hearts, 5 of diamonds, Queen of spades

Now, in this badugi card game I want to create two loops where the first loop checks if all the ranks are different(none of them can be the same) and the other loop checks if all the suits are different. If both of these conditions return as true where they all have different ranks and suits, the hand has drawn a badugi(please excuse my lack of terminology where necessary.)

Now, how can I create an efficient loop for such a situation? I was thinking that I could create several if statements as such:

```
if (hand.charAt(0) != hand.charAt(2) && hand.charAt(0) != hand.charAt(4) && hand.charAt(0) != hand.charAt(6))
if (hand.charAt(2) != hand.charAt(0) && hand.charAt(2) != hand.charAt(4) && hand.charAt(2) != hand.charAt(6))
```

... and so forth comparing every single index to one another. But this gets tedious and seems very unprofessional. So my question is, how do I write an efficient loop for this scenario? How can I compare/check if there are no matches at these specific index points to one another?

If I haven't explained properly then please let me know.

Please keep in mind, I am not allowed freedom of how to formulate a hand. It has to be in the format above

Comment: How can it be possible for 5 cards to all have different suits?

Comment: Good point. Changed to 4

Comment: Are you allowed to use a `Set`?

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to use loops?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39778939/how-can-i-use-several-conditions-in-a-loop-to-compare-different-indexes-of-a-str?rq=1 - same issue, same homework question.

Comment: @SusanW It's only the same representation, not the same issue: that question requires checking for a flush, thus checking that all five cards have the same suit. In this question, they are supposed to be different.

Comment: @AeriaGlorisia Thank you very much for the timely accept!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are putting your energy into the wrong place.

You do not need to worry about **efficiency** at all.

Instead, you should worry about creating a clean design (based on reasonable abstractions) and then write code that is super-easy to read and understand.

And your current approach fails both of those ideas; unfortunately completely.

In other words: you do **not** represent hands and values as characters within a String.

You create a class that **abstracts** a Card (with its value and face).
And then a "hand" becomes a List / array of such Card objects. And then you can use concepts such as [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to compare card values, or you can make use of [equals()](https://www.sitepoint.com/implement-javas-equals-method-correctly/) ...

And even when you wish to keep your (actually over-complex) naive, simple approach of using chars within a string; then you should at least use some kind of looping so that you don't compare charAt(0) against charAt(2); but maybe charAt(i) against charAt(j).

And following your edit and the excellent comment by jsheeran: even when you are forced to deal with this kind of "string notation"; you could still write **reasonable** code ... that takes such string as input, but transforms them into something that makes more sense.

For example, the Card class constructor could take two chars for suite/value.

But to get you going with your actual question; you could **something** like:

```
public boolean isCardDistinctFromAllOtherCards(int indexToCheck) {
  for (int i=0; i<cardString.length-1; i+=2) {
    if (i == indexToCheck) {
      continue;
    }
    if (cardString.charAt(indexToCheck) == cardString.charAt(i)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

( the above is just an **idea** how to write down a method that checks that all chars at 0, 2, 4, ... are not matching some index x).

Comment: I am not allowed freedom in how I choose how to create the hand. It has to be in this format.

Comment: Can't you implement the hand as @GhostCat suggests, and give it a constructor which takes your string as an argument?

Answer (score 1):

You should really think about your design, like creating `Card` class etc., but back to the question now, since it's not gonna solve it.

I suggest adding all 4 values to a `Set` and then checking if size of the `Set` is `4`. You can even shortcut it and while adding this `yourSet.add(element)` return false then it means there is already that element in the set and they are not unique. That hardly matters here since you only need to add `4` elements, but it may be useful in the future if you work with more elements.

Comment: I meant with ranks, not suits.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice creating an array with these chars you are referencing just to clean up the fact you are using indices. i.e create a vals array and a suits array.

This would be my suggestion by using a return or break the loop will stop this means when a match is found it wont have to loop through the rest of the elements .. Hope this helps !

```
private static int check(char[] vals, char[] suits){
 int flag;
  for(int i=0; i<=vals.length-2;i++){
    for(int k=vals.length-1; k<=0;k++){
        if(vals[i]==vals[k]){
            flag=-1;
            return flag;
        }
        if(suits[i]==suits[k]){
            flag=1;
            return flag;
        }
    }
  }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply iterate over your string and check for same ranks or suits:

```
    public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(checkRanks("2s3h5dQs"));
        System.out.println(checkSuits("2s3h5dQs"));
    }
    public static boolean checkRanks(String hand){
        List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i< hand.length(); i+=2){
            if (!list.contains(hand.charAt(i))){
               list.add(hand.charAt(i));
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
      return true;    
    }
    public static boolean checkSuits(String hand){
        List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i< hand.length(); i+=2){
            if (!list.contains(hand.charAt(i))){
               list.add(hand.charAt(i));
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
      return true;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Why list rather than set? It's O(n) vs. O(1) (well, not that much different when we're talking about 4 elements, but as a principle).